# How to use pyautogui in remote server?

Tags: pyautogui

I want to open chrome dev tools and enter some command.
automation scripts:

```
def open_dev_tools():
    pyautogui.keyDown('f12')
    pyautogui.keyUp('f12')
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
    pyautogui.press('p')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')`
```

When I ran the scripts calling remote grid in my local. It always use my local keyboard. how to use the remote server keyboard.

I have no ideas about it.

Comment: How are you executing the script on the remote server?

Comment: How do you connect to the remote server?